# The results from DLL in Delphi where the parameters are PAnsiChar

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

i've got a small problem.
In my DLL i've got:

```
uses
  ShareMem,
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Dialogs;

function My_func (Param1, Param2, Param3: PAnsiChar) : Integer;

var
  s1,s2,s3 : string;

begin

     s1 := string(Param1);
     s2 := string(Param2);
     s3 := string(Param3);
     ShowMessage(s1);
     ShowMessage(s2);
     ShowMessage(s3);

     My_func := 0;
end;
```

And the call from my TestUnit.pas

```
unit Utestunit;

interface

uses
  ShareMem, Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,  Dialogs;

procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TMy_func = function (Param1, Param2, Param3: PAnsiChar) : Integer; StdCall;
var
  my_func : TMyfunc;

  error_code:integer;
  My_library : THandle;
  the_end : Boolean;
  path_library,
  path_library_full : string;

  test1,
  test2,
  test3 : array [0..255] of AnsiChar;
begin
  // open the DLL
  path_library := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'DLL\RS_DLL.dll';
  path_library_full := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'DLL\';
  SetCurrentDir(path_library_full);
  try
    the_end := False;
    My_library := SafeLoadLibrary(PChar(path_library));
    if My_library > 32 then
    begin
        @My_func := GetProcAddress(My_library, PChar('My_func'));
        if @My_func = nil then
        begin
          ShowMessage('There is no library in '+path_library);
          the_end := True;
        end;
    end
    else
    begin
      error_code := GetLastError;
      ShowMessage('Błąd biblioteki '+ sciezka_biblioteki+' nr:'+IntToStr(error_code));
      the_end := True;
    end;

    if not the_end then
    begin
      // the calling

      test1 := 'My string nr 1';
      test2 := 'My string nr 2';
      test3 := 'My string nr 3';

      kod_bledu := My_func(
          test1,
          test2,
          test3
      );      
    end;

  finally
    FreeLibrary(My_library);
    SetCurrentDir(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName))
  end;
end;
```

The results are:

```
My string nr 1

trash

trash
```

as the messages from my DLL.

Why only the first result is good while the rest trash is?
It's only the test in my app.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of very bad habits in this code, that I don't want to get into because it will take so much effort.

However, the reason for the behaviour is that you did not declare the function in the DLL as `stdcall`. Fix that and the text will be passed correctly.

Comment: Thx David. You were right about missing `stdcall'. And btw what 'bad habits' do you see? The library is dynamiclly loaded, the strings i need are in PAnsiChar.... So?

Comment: Using Sharemem is pointless. No need to use those fixed length arrays. The code to load the DLL is plain wrong. That check against 32 is wrong. There is a crappy blog post that people have copied for years with that code in.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sure software based on that blog post was sold and lives in the wild. Maybe even in drivers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Would you be so kind and present the "right way" to handle DLL in Delphi? Maybe someone who search for good solutions will read this post and use your advices. Before i've decided to post here i've looked for solutions on many internet pages and i saw plenty of examples, but i would not be allowed to critise. When some solutions works good - its's the right solution. But if there's a better - it's the rigth to show it (share it) for the rest of the poeple who read this.

Comment: Read the documentation for `LoadLibrary`. There's no mention of this magic number 32. It returns `NULL`, aka `0` if the function fails.